# How to log entire svg document?

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to print the entire the SVG document in the console..like...

```
<svg id="mainSVG">
....
   <g>
       <rect>..</rect>
   </g>
...
</svg>
```

I tried, console.log(svgDoc) but it simply prints 'Object SVGDocument'. Please note that I am doing it in IE9.

Thanks

Venkatesh Laguduva

Comment: I don't understand what you need to do. Can you be more specific?

Comment: You should edit your question above rather than adding a comment.  Include clear a description of what you are trying to achieve and what you have already tried.

Comment: For browsers other than IE9 you use the hierarchy inspector, right-click on the SVG element and choose "Copy as HTML".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var xmlString = serializer.serializeToString(svgDoc);
console.log(xmlString);
```